# Excel VBA Export to text file. Need to delete blank line

Tags: excel, vba, export, line

I have a workbook that I export to a text file using the below script.  It works fine but when I open the text file there is always a blank line at the end that caused me issues with another script I run after I generate this text file.  Any help at all on how I can remove the blank line from my export.

Code:

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Save file name and path into a variable
    template_file = ActiveWorkbook.FullName   

' Default directory would be c:\temp.  Users however will have the ability 
' to change where to save the file if need be.

      fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        InitialFileName:="C:\users\%username%\SNSCA_Customer_" + _
        VBA.Strings.Format(Now, "mmddyyyy") + ".txt", _
        fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

    If fileSaveName = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Save file as .txt TAB delimited fileSaveName, FileFormat:=36,

       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        fileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows, _
        CreateBackup:=False

       file_name_saved = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    MsgBox "Your SNSCA configuration upload file has been " _
       & "successfully created at: " & vbCr & vbCr & file_name_saved

End Sub
```

Edit...

Here is the alternate that is not working either:

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim exportTxt As String
    fPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\Sample_" & Format(Now(), "HHNNSS") & ".txt"

    exportTxt = ActiveWorkbook.

    Open fPath For Append As #1    'write the new file
    Print #1, exportTxt;
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: That may be happening for so many reasons in given input excel doc. But you can read the file immediately after saving and remove extra lines.

Comment: I'd say your other script is too sensitive... Change it so it doesn't choke on a trailing blank line!

Comment: I was trying to change the way the VBA exports the active worksheet but this doesn't seem to work.. I cannot get the below variable exporttxt to save as all the content of the active worksheet like the saveas from what I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

While I have upticked the comment from Jean-François Corbett you can use this VBA below to remove the last line of your txt file (As you stated a blank line is written when saving this way).

This VBA is based on a commonly used [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) routine. It

- reads in your newly created text file, for example (*SNSCA_Customer_01092012.txt*)
- splits it line by line
- then rewrites all the lines except the the last to a new txt file(*SNSCA_Customer_01092012clean.txt*)

  ```
  Sub Rectangle1_Click()
  Dim strTemplateFile As String
  Dim strFname As String
  Dim strFnameClean As String
  Dim FileSaveName

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ' Save file name and path into a variable
  strTemplateFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

  ' Default directory would be c:\temp.  Users however will have the ability
  ' to change where to save the file if need be.

  FileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
                 InitialFileName:="C:\users\%username%\SNSCA_Customer_" + _
                                  VBA.Strings.Format(Now, "mmddyyyy") + ".txt", _
                 fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

  If FileSaveName = False Then
      Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Save file as .txt TAB delimited fileSaveName, FileFormat:=36,
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
                        FileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlTextWindows, _
                        CreateBackup:=False

  strFname = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  strFnameClean = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".txt", "clean.txt")
  MsgBox "Your SNSCA configuration upload file has been " _
       & "successfully created at: " & vbCr & vbCr & strFname
  Call Test(strFname, strFnameClean)
  End Sub


  Sub Test(ByVal strFname, ByVal strFnameClean)
  Const ForReading = 1
  Const ForWriting = 2

  Dim objFSO As Object
  Dim objTF As Object
  Dim strAll As String
  Dim varTxt
  Dim lngRow As Long

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objTF = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFname, ForReading)
  strAll = objTF.readall
  objTF.Close
  Set objTF = objFSO.createTextFile(strFnameClean, ForWriting)
  varTxt = Split(strAll, vbCrLf)
  For lngRow = LBound(varTxt) To UBound(varTxt) - 1
      objTF.writeline varTxt(lngRow)
  Next
  objTF.Close
  End Sub
  ```