# One Empty row in file generated from macros in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to split a file with 120 records into files of at-most 50 records each. So expectation is it should genarate 2 files with 50 records and 1 file wit 20 but what I am getting is 2 files of 51 records with 1 empty record in the end and 3rd file with 21 records with 1 empty record in the end.

I want to remove last blank line from all three files. Below is the code used -
This code was suggested in [Empty rows in file generated from macros in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70568489/empty-rows-in-file-generated-from-macros-in-excel/70571917#70571917)

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitAndSaveFile()
    Const ProcName As String = "SplitAndSaveFile"
    Dim dwbCount As Long ' Generated Workbooks Count
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Source
    Const swsName As String = "Data"
    Const sCol As String = "A"
    Const sfRow As Long = 4
    
    ' Destination
    Const dfCellAddress As String = "A1" ' needs to be 'A' since entire rows.
    Const dMaxRows As Long = 50
    Const dNameSuffix As String = "_Part"
    ' In the loop, this will be replaced by a number ('dwbCount').
    Const dIdPlaceHolder As String = "?" ' the '?' is illegal for file names
    ' The following two lines are dependent on each other.
    Const dFileExtension As String = ".txt"
    Dim dFileFormat As XlFileFormat: dFileFormat = xlText
    
    ' Create a reference to the source first cell ('sfCell').
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(swsName)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Cells(sfRow, sCol)
    
    ' Calculate the number of records (rows) ('drCount').
    
    ' This will find the last non-blank cell i.e. cells containing
    ' formulas evaluating to an empty string are ignored.
    ' Make sure that the worksheet is not filtered and there are no hidden
    ' cells.
    Dim slCell As Range
    Set slCell = sfCell.Resize(sws.Rows.Count - sfRow + 1) _
        .Find("*", , xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If slCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = slCell.Row
    
    ' This is the preferred way, but besides a few pros, it behaves like 'End'
    ' i.e. it will find the last non-empty cell. A cell is not empty
    ' if it contains a formula evaluating to an empty string ('""'):
    ' it is blank.
    'Dim slCell As Range
    'Set slCell = sfCell.Resize(sws.Rows.Count - sfRow + 1) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    'If slCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    'Dim slRow As Long: slRow = slCell.Row
    
    ' The classic last row using 'End' will find the last non-empty cell.
    'Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, sCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = slRow - sfRow + 1
    If drCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data (highly unlikely but...)
    
    ' Determine the generic file path (dwbGenericFilePath)
    Dim swbBaseName As String: swbBaseName = swb.Name
    Dim DotPosition As String: DotPosition = InStrRev(swb.Name, ".")
    If DotPosition > 0 Then swbBaseName = Left(swbBaseName, DotPosition - 1)
    Dim dwbExtension As String: dwbExtension = dFileExtension
    If Left(dwbExtension, 1) <> "." Then dwbExtension = "." & dwbExtension
    Dim dwbGenericFilePath As String
    dwbGenericFilePath = swb.Path & Application.PathSeparator & swbBaseName _
        & dNameSuffix & dIdPlaceHolder & dwbExtension

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Additional variables used in the loop.
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dfCell As Range
    Dim dFilePath As String
    
    Do Until drCount = 0
        ' Create a reference to the current source range.
        If drCount > dMaxRows Then ' all workbooks but the last
            Set srg = sfCell.Resize(dMaxRows).EntireRow
            Set sfCell = sfCell.Offset(dMaxRows)
            drCount = drCount - dMaxRows
        Else ' the last workbook
            Set srg = sfCell.Resize(drCount).EntireRow
            drCount = 0
        End If
        ' Copy the current source range to the current destination range.
        dwbCount = dwbCount + 1 ' count the number of generated workbooks
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' one worksheet only
        Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(1)
        Set dfCell = dws.Range(dfCellAddress)
        srg.Copy dfCell
        ' Save and close the current destination workbook.
        dFilePath = Replace(dwbGenericFilePath, dIdPlaceHolder, CStr(dwbCount))
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, dFileFormat
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Loop

ProcExit:

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Select Case dwbCount
    Case 0
        MsgBox "No files generated.", vbCritical, ProcName
    Case 1
        MsgBox "One file generated.", vbInformation, ProcName
    Case Else
        MsgBox dwbCount & " files generated.", vbInformation, ProcName
    End Select

    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you viewing the text file and counting the rows  ? In a text editor , if so which  one ?

Comment: From a Notepad file

Comment: All 50 lines have a line ending so in notepad the cursor will appear at the end of the file which is the start of the 51st line. What is the problem  , are you having difficulty importing the file into another application ?

Comment: Yes, I need to upload the file in another application and with extra line it is throwing an error (ERROR Line 3 incorrectly formatted. Only 5 fields instead of 33)

Comment: Do you have lines (ie  row 6) where some of the end columns are blank ? I suspect the problem is not the 'extra' line but the short lines. How many columns potentially have data in them and need to be included in the text file, is it A to AG ?

Comment: No, there was no extra line/ column in last row, In all other rows, it should have 33 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a text file, scan down the sheet creating lines by joining the columns with a tab character. Write the last line without line ending.

```vb
Sub SplitAndSaveFile()

    Const BATCH = 50
    Const LASTCOL = "AG" ' 33 columns

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim startrow As Long, lastrow As Long, endrow As Long
    Dim folder As String, partname As String, textname As String
    Dim text As String, s As String
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    folder = wb.Path & "\"
    partname = Replace(wb.Name, ".xlsm", "") + "_Part"
    
    Dim FSO As Object, ts As Object, ar, fields
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    n = 0
    With wb.Sheets("Data")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ar = .Range("A4:" & LASTCOL & lastrow).Value
        
        For startrow = 1 To UBound(ar) Step BATCH
            n = n + 1
            endrow = startrow + BATCH - 1
            If endrow > UBound(ar) Then endrow = UBound(ar)
            
            ' create text file
            textname = folder & partname & Format(n, "00") & ".txt"
            Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile(textname, overwrite:=True, Unicode:=True) ' ascii false
            
            ' write data as tab delimited
            For i = startrow To endrow
                ReDim fields(1 To UBound(ar, 2))
                For j = 1 To UBound(fields)
                    fields(j) = ar(i, j)
                Next
                If i = endrow Then
                    ts.write Join(fields, vbTab) ' last line no CRLF
                Else
                    ts.writeline Join(fields, vbTab)
                End If
            Next
            ts.Close
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox n & " File(s) generated.", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code, I am getting an error "Run Time 52" from line "Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile(textname, overwrite:=True, Unicode:=True) ' ascii false"

Comment: While you're at it, also look into the 'non-blank cell' comments in the code to get the last row since there are probably formulas evaluating to an empty string at the bottom of the data, so `End` will not do but `Find` with `xlValues` will. Also, to get the last column you could easily use `LastCol = ws.UsedRange.Columns(ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column`.

Comment: @nikita Is the workbook on a network drive ? are you on mac or windows. ? are there formula on the sheet ? what is the workbook name ?

Comment: Yes, it is on Network Drive and I am working on Windows. There is no Formulas in the sheet and the workbook name is "ATM Locator Data Template_V4.xlsm"

Comment: @nikita can you try it on a local drive.

Comment: All of our files are linked with OneDrive - so can't separate it. Also, noticed that issue was in textname = wb.path & partname & Format(n, "00") & ".txt"
            Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile(textname, overwrite:=True, Unicode:=True).... When we remove wb.path, then macro is running properly.... But it is always saved in Documents, we would need to save it in same folder as source file

Comment: @nikita Aside from the text files being created in the wrong place do they upload OK ?

Comment: Yes, they upload okay now, final code that I am using is  textname = partname & Format(n, "00") & ".txt"
            Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile(textname, overwrite:=True, Unicode:=True)

Comment: Is the OneDrive synced to a local drive that you could use in place of `workbook.path` like `C:\Users\username\OneDrive\etc"

Comment: In original code we were using textname = folder & partname & Format(n, "00") & ".txt"
            Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile(textname, overwrite:=True, Unicode:=True) where folder = wb.Path & "\"....... I have checked wb.path and it is giving correct path.

Comment: Yes, path is coming as C:\Users\Username\OneDrive\Desktop\RPA - ATM Locator

Comment: When I try to write message for path it is showing as "https://drive.abc.com/personal/email_id/Documents/Desktop/RPA-ATM Locator" using command msgBox wb.path

Comment: @nikita try `folder = "C:\Users\Username\OneDrive\Desktop\RPA - ATM Locator\" `

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/12704593/cdp1802 My file is in this folder only but when I try to get the path from vba it is showing as "https://drive.abc.com/personal/email_id/Documents/Desktop/RPA-ATM Locator"

Comment: I just tried to check the path using my original code where the files are saving in similar path and in that as well the path is  same. So, there should not be issue with the path I believe..... 
There code was - 
dwbGenericFilePath = swb.Path & Application.PathSeparator & swbBaseName _
        & dNameSuffix & dIdPlaceHolder & dwbExtension

Comment: It is resolved now with below change - partname = Replace(folder + wb.Name, ".xlsm", "") + "_Part"................. Thanks very much for your support. :)